# What does 'par' mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Cantrell's latest focus is Phantom Space, one in a sea of new launch
> startups seeking to take advantage of the explosion of smaller,
> cheaper satellite designs and build rockets that can meet the growing
> demand to launch these payloads into orbit. But as is ***par*** for
> the course with Cantrell, Phantom is trying to find success by
> swimming against the current.

What does 'par' mean here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Be par for the course" is a phrase which is defined as below in [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-par-for-the-course):

> If a type of behaviour, event, or situation is par for the course, *it is not good but it is normal or as you would expect*

So here, we can rewrite that sentence as "But *as is expected with Cantrell*, Phantom is trying to find success by swimming against the current.

Hope that helps..

Comment: Thanks! But what do you mean by 'expected with'? Shouldn't it be 'expected by'?

Comment: Yes, "expected by" can be a more proper usage.

Answer (score 0):

'Par' is average, or normal. What happens as a matter of course (sic).

'Par for the course' references the sport of golf. It's the number of strokes an average player would take to get round. 1,2,3 or 4 drives to the green, and a maximum of 2 putts. Played by a 'proficient' golfer.

Par can be used on its own, as in above/below par, and often 'for the course' is implicit.

EDIT: there's a sort of irony here, though. If one is 'below par', one is not doing too well. However, if one is 'below par' *on the golfcourse*, one is doing better than average..!